# Efficient way of computing multivariate gaussian varying the mean - Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, gaussian

Is there a efficient way to do the computation of a multivariate gaussian (as below) that returns matrix p , that is, making use of some sort of vectorization? I am aware that matrix p is symmetric, but still for a matrix of size 40000x3, for example, this will take quite a long time.

Matlab code example:

```
DataMatrix = [3 1 4; 1 2 3; 1 5 7; 3 4 7; 5 5 1; 2 3 1; 4 4 4];

[rows, cols ] = size(DataMatrix);

I = eye(cols);
p = zeros(rows);

for k = 1:rows

    p(k,:) = mvnpdf(DataMatrix(:,:),DataMatrix(k,:),I);

end
```

Comment: `mvnpdf` is already vectorized.

Comment: Would the third argument to `mvnpdf` always be an identity matrix in your actual case?

Comment: Yeah, the covariance matrix wouldn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stage 1: Hack into source code

Iteratively we are performing `mvnpdf(DataMatrix(:,:),DataMatrix(k,:),I)`

The syntax is : `mvnpdf(X,Mu,Sigma)`.

Thus, the correspondence with our input becomes :

```
X = DataMatrix(:,:);
Mu = DataMatrix(k,:);
Sigma = I
```

For the sizes relevant to our situation, the source code `mvnpdf.m` reduces to -

```
%// Store size parameters of X
[n,d] = size(X);

%// Get vector mean, and use it to center data
X0 = bsxfun(@minus,X,Mu);

%// Make sure Sigma is a valid covariance matrix
[R,err] = cholcov(Sigma,0);

%// Create array of standardized data, and compute log(sqrt(det(Sigma)))
xRinv = X0 / R;
logSqrtDetSigma = sum(log(diag(R)));

%// Finally get the quadratic form and thus, the final output
quadform = sum(xRinv.^2, 2);
p_out = exp(-0.5*quadform - logSqrtDetSigma - d*log(2*pi)/2)
```

Now, if the Sigma is always an identity matrix, we would have `R` as an identity matrix too. Therefore, `X0 / R` would be same as `X0`, which is saved as `xRinv`. So, essentially `quadform = sum(X0.^2, 2);`

Thus, the original code -

```
for k = 1:rows
    p(k,:) = mvnpdf(DataMatrix(:,:),DataMatrix(k,:),I);
end
```

reduces to -

```
[n,d] = size(DataMatrix);
[R,err] = cholcov(I,0);
p_out = zeros(rows);
K = sum(log(diag(R))) + d*log(2*pi)/2;
for k = 1:rows  
    X0 = bsxfun(@minus,DataMatrix,DataMatrix(k,:));     
    quadform = sum(X0.^2, 2);
    p_out(k,:) = exp(-0.5*quadform - K);
end
```

Now, if the input matrix is of size `40000x3`, you might want to stop here. But with system resources permitting, you can vectorize everything as discussed next.

### Stage 2: Vectorize everything

Now that we see what's actually going on and that the computations look parallelizable, it's time to step-up to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) in `3D` with his good friend [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
%// Get size params and R
[n,d] = size(DataMatrix);
[R,err] = cholcov(I,0);

%// Calculate constants : "logSqrtDetSigma" and  "d*log(2*pi)/2`"
K1 = sum(log(diag(R)));
K2 = d*log(2*pi)/2;

%// Major thing happening here as we calclate "X0" for all iterations
%// in one go with permute and bsxfun
diffs = bsxfun(@minus,DataMatrix,permute(DataMatrix,[3 2 1]));

%// "Sigma" is an identity matrix, so it plays no in "/R" at "xRinv = X0 / R".
%// Perform elementwise squaring and summing rows to get vectorized "quadform"
quadform1 = squeeze(sum(diffs.^2,2))

%// Finally use "quadform1" and get vectorized output as a 2D array
p_out = exp(-0.5*quadform1 - K1 - K2)
```

Comment: @Guilherme Would you be kind enough to let me know the kind of speedups you are getting with the proposed solution(s), if any?

Comment: for a matrix of size (10000,3) I got about 11.5 seconds and 3.7 seconds for the for loop approach and the vetorized form approach respectively.

Comment: unfortunately for the case of a huge matrix such as 40000x3, the vectorization procedure doesn't work well due to memory complications.... for my application i was working with the rows of matrix p independently, so I didn't have this particular memory issue. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Guilherme Well yeah vectorized codes need *room* to work and with such huge datasizes, it's hard to give them the same. Thanks for getting back with the profiler results!